# How to use filling in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I want to fill region between different contours, e.g. `ContourPlot[{c1 = f1, c2 = f2}, ...]` a la the filling options for `Plot` like `Filling -> {1->{2}}`. Is it an easier way than superimposing two contour plots then manually excluding regions?

Comment: I think some times it will not be so clear for implicit  functions to say something analogous to `Filling -> {1->{2}}`. eg. `ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, Sin[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2}, {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 12}]`. btw maybe it will be `RegionPlot` what you are looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think some times it will not be so clear for implicit functions to say something analogous to `Filling -> {1->{2}}` as it is in `Plot`. Anyway, maybe it will be `RegionPlot` what you are looking for. But in that case you might still need superimposing two `Graphics`.

Here is an example:

```
curvegraph = 
  ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/5, Sin[x] + Cos[y] == 1/10},
     {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
     ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thick]}];

shadinggraph = 
  RegionPlot[(Cos[x] + Cos[y] <= 1/5 && 
      Sin[x] + Cos[y] >= 1/10) || (Cos[x] + Cos[y] >= 1/5 && 
      Sin[x] + Cos[y] <= 1/10), {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Lighter[Orange, .9]];

Show[{shadinggraph, curvegraph}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It seems to be what the OP wanted, +1.

Comment: Awesome answer - almost what I wanted! I was hoping for a nice option since it does get tedious writing the conditions for RegionPlot. Thanks for the pointer to RegionPlot though; now I just need to cook some automating functions.

Comment: @Artes Thanks :) I'm not sure what the OP exactly want. There could be many possibilities for implicit function curves..

Comment: @polyglot Thanks. Though it looks not so trivial for me to fill areas between free curves automaticly.. Maybe you could introduce some dynamic things to manually specify (eg. using mouse/`Locator`s etc.) areas you want to fill.

Answer (score 10):

It seems you would rather use `RegionPlot` instead of `ContourPlot`.

Let's define e.g.

```
f[x_] := x^2 - x y + y^2 - 3
g[x_] := x^2 + 5 x y - 3 y^2 - 2
```

then

```
ContourPlot[{f[x] == 2, g[x] == 3}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

or  one could use `ContourPlot` this way :

```
ContourPlot[f[x] - 2, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> 11,
                       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, g[x] - 3 < 0]]
```

[image]

while

```
RegionPlot[{f[x] - 2 > 0, g[x] - 3 < 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

or extracting only regions between curves

```
GraphicsGrid[ Table[ RegionPlot[ a[g[x] - 3, 0] && b[f[x] - 2, 0], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                                 Axes -> True, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Darker @ Green}],
                     {a, {Greater, Less}}, {b, {Greater, Less}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Silvia Thanks, questions while not well posed are interpretable in many different ways, however interpretations are sometimes close enough.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account István's comment and the nice example of Silvia, I used Presentations again (which I sell) to produce a filled plot using overlays with low opacity. The problem here is to convert the contour Lines into Polygons, both the Lines that meet a common edge of the plot and the Lines that span a corner. Here is the routine for that:

```
CompleteThePolygon[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}] := 
 Line[points : {first : {xfirst_, yfirst_}, __, 
     last : {xlast_, ylast_}}] :>
  Module[{xcorner, ycorner},
   Which[
    first == last, Polygon[points],
    xfirst == xlast || yfirst == ylast, Polygon[Join[points, {first}]],
    True,
    xcorner = 
     First[Select[{xfirst, xlast}, MatchQ[#, N[xmin | xmax]] &]]; 
    ycorner = 
     First[Select[{yfirst, ylast}, MatchQ[#, N[ymin | ymax]] &]];
    Polygon[Join[points, {{xcorner, ycorner}, first}]]]
   ]
```

Then this is the plot.

```
Draw2D[
 {EdgeForm[Black],
  MapThread[{#2, (ContourDraw[#1, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}] // 
        Normal) /. 
      CompleteThePolygon[{{0, 4 \[Pi]}, {0, 4 \[Pi]}}]} &, {{Cos[x] + 
       Cos[y] == 1/5, Sin[x] + Cos[y] == 1/10}, {Opacity[0.4, Orange],
      Opacity[0.3, Lighter@Blue]}}]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLabel -> "Lines to Polygons",
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]

This may not be exactly what is wanted because it fills all the regions of overlap.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
           ContourLabels -> True, Contours -> {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, -0.2, -0.4, -0.6, -0.8}, 
           ContourShading -> {None, Lighter[Pink], Lighter[Blue], Lighter[Green]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As István points out on David's post, this answer has nothing to do with the OP's question, which is about filling between the contours of two equalities, not filling between the contours of a single function.

Answer (score -2):

The solution of Beste and Sekto is pretty good and uses regular Mathematica. The only downside is the chore of picking all the filling colors.

One place where this consideration comes in is in a contour plot that has rather large plateaus with small variation in value that fill much of the area of the plot. The Presentations Application, which I sell, has a feature to automatically handle this. Here is a typical case:

```
<< Presentations`
contourlist = {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.85, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 
   0.99, 1};
Draw2D[
 {ContourDraw[
   Cos[(x + 1/2)^2 ( y - 1/2)] Cos[y], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
     2}, {y, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
   Contours -> contourlist,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["RedBlueTones"][1 - #] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotRange -> Automatic]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLabel -> "Using Default Gradient Coloring",
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]

The ContourColors ColorFunction will automatically pick distinguished colors based on the contour list.

```
contourlist = {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.85, 0.9, 0.925, 0.95, 
   0.99, 1};
Draw2D[
 {ContourDraw[
   Cos[(x + 1/2)^2 ( y - 1/2)] Cos[y], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
     2}, {y, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2},
   Contours -> contourlist,
   ColorFunction -> 
    ContourColors[contourlist, ColorData["RedBlueTones"][1 - #] &],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotRange -> Automatic]},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True,
 PlotLabel -> "Using a ContourColors",
 ImageSize -> 300
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: David, I think your answer (and @Beste's) has nothing to do with the OP's question: that is about filling between the contours of *two* equalities instead of filling between the contours of a single function.